# WPF ListView doesn't stick anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sticky, scrollviewer

I have a fairly simple `ListView`:

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource defaultViewModelTemplateSelector}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Trades}">
</ListView>
```

With a fairly simple `ViewModel`:

```
private void OnNewTrade(TradeLog trade)
{
    _View.Show(); //makes sure the window is visible on a new trade
    lock (Trades.Lock)
    {
        Trades.Insert(0, new TradeLogViewModel(trade));
    }
}
```

It has been working as expected for several years now, but today, several users (all but one) have noticed a change of behavior where new elements added aren't in view. They're added to the top of the list but the `ScrollViewer` doesn't stick to top anymore.

No code has been changed. Has anyone noticed this problem? I've seen notes in the October 2022 .Net Framework release notes (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-framework-october-2022-security-and-quality-rollup/):

> Blockquote
> Addresses issues arising in TreeView (or ListBox/DataGrid with grouping enabled) when changing the underlying collection(s) while also collapsing or expanding TreeView nodes. Scrolling actions, especially “short” actions like LineUp or MouseWheelUp, can result in poor outcomes: hangs, crashes, unexpected scrolling, gaps in the display, etc.

Has anyone also noticed a change in behavior? Do we now have to bend over backwards to get expected behavior? I'm very confused.

Comment: That update does not sound like it would affect you but regardless, you can ensure newly added items are visible merely by calling the `ScrollIntoView` function after adding them.

Comment: I've uninstalled the update to confirm it was the culprit. Behavior goes back to normal after uninstalling. Simply calling `ScrollIntoView` doesn't cut it because it would prevent a user from scrolling down. My solution until confirming the update was the culprit was to add a `mvvmlight` `EventToCommand` mapper to the `ListView`'s ScrollChanged, then in the event check previous scroll offset and, if it was 0 and the new value was 1, ignore change by accessing the evt source and setting it's `ScrollOffset` to 0. Didn't want to apply to every `ListVew` and `DataGrid` in the solution...